# legacy bitfield compatibility issue on ARM

Tags: arm, bit-fields

I am working on porting legacy code from a PowerPC onto an ARM.  The original developer used bitfields throughout a very important piece of the code.  When I cross-compile with the ARM toolchain, I get

```
warning: multiple accesses to volatile structure member because of packed attribute [-  fstrict-volatile-bitfields]
```

This is apparently due to the way the bitfield is packed and offset, which appears to be incompatible with the ARM toolchain.  I see that a patch for GCC was released, but it doesn't look like it actually fixed the issue (I personally have not tried the patch yet).

For example, the bitfield is defined in the header file

```
typedef struct
   {  
   T8    BitFieldOffset;     //current bit offset value
   Tsv32 Data; //extracted bit field (may be exp_golomb- unsigned or signed)
   }  __pack__ TExtractBits;
   Tn8* extractBitField (Tn8 *pBuf, TExtractBits *pExtractBits, T32 numFieldBits);
```

Then in the .cpp,

```
TExtractBits teb;
teb.BitFieldOffset = 0;
pBuf = extractBitField(pBuf, &teb, 1); TimeCode_DropFrame = teb.Data;
pBuf = extractBitField(pBuf, &teb, 5); TimeCode_Hours = teb.Data;
pBuf = extractBitField(pBuf, &teb, 6); TimeCode_Minutes = teb.Data;
```

Is their a clever way of making this code more cross-platform friendly?  I would like to make as few direct changes to this code as possible.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Bitfields work in ARM.  Show some code.

Comment: It appears that the bitfield is part of a volatile member of the structure and to properly access it, the compiler needs to generate multiple access to the area considered volatile. It is warning you that you may get unexpected behavior. As stark said, code would be a good reference.

Comment: bitfields are very very bad, never use them, they are not portable, not between compilers not between targets.  What you are seeing is expected and has nothing to do with ARM.

Comment: Added code.  The extracted bitfield Data is set as a volatile signed long.  I have already tried changing its type to signed long and just long, which removes the compiler warnings.  However the program still seg faults when it is run on the board.